# SherlockFragment's, rotations and onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

I have an app with several SherlockFragmentActivities and SherlockFragment. I'm having trouble with supporting rotation and transition between the activities.

In my first SherlockFragmentActivity, I attempt to catch the rotations with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        InitializeUI();
        details = new MeetingConnectFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
               R.id.activity_scheduled_meeting_connect, details).commit();      
    } 
}
//this is called when the screen rotates.
// (onCreate is no longer called when screen rotates due to manifest, see: android:configChanges)
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    InitializeUI();
    details = new MeetingConnectFragment();
    details.setInfo(cInfo);
    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.replace(R.id.activity_scheduled_meeting_details, details);
    trans.addToBackStack(null);
            trans.commit();     
}

private void InitializeUI() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meeting_connect);
    // other stuff cut for brevity
}
```

Within the MeetinConnectFragment there is a button that will bring up a different activity. If the user rotates the screen while in the 2nd activity, then returns to this activity, the program crashes with the exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17976): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1299)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1310)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at com.level3.connect.meetings.MeetingConnectActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MeetingConnectActivity.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3675)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleActivityConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3849)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
 E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
E/AndroidRuntime(17976):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The exception is on the line to commit the change. I've been trying to figure out how to handle this scenario but am not quite there. Help appreciated.

Comment: That log doesn't quite include the full Exception. Can you post the rest?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I've updated the post with the rest of the exception.Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing all handling of the configuration / rotation and letting Android handle it In order to do this, I had to remove the code to check if the savedInstanceState was null in onCreate in the Activity. Each time the activity is created, it will re-create the fragment.

I'll have to run some tests to see if this causes a memory leak - perhaps I need to destroy the old fragment first.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your call to `InitializeUI()` below `trans.commit()`.

When the Activity sets a new content view, it will call `onSaveInstanceState()`, and thus you receive the IllegalStateException you are seeing.